# How to fully access windows machine as an administrator using python

Tags: python, windows, admin, administration, administrator

I am on a project in which I need to have full access of each directory or file in the windows file system,I am using python for it.But I cant modify or access some files and totally inaccessible the C:/ drive with python,showing "permission denied".

I want to know is there any kind of way to get the full access as administrator using python,please suggest and help.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 0):

For me the easiest solution is an administrator terminal instance.

1. Press the start/window button
2. Enter the search field
3. Type in cmd and wait until under programs cmd.exe is found
4. right click on that program
5. click on the option where you can execute as an administrator
6. Now your terminal has administrator rights. When you start a python skript inside that terminal the python interpreter has also amdin rights.

Comment: If Python's installer added a "runas" verb, you'd be able to right-click a script and choose "Run as administrator". I usually add this by copying the "open" key, i.e. `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Python.File\Shell\open`, to a "runas" key under "Shell".

Comment: Another option is to create a shortcut (.LNK file) to the script and in its advanced properties select "Run as administrator". Then add `.LNK` to the `PATHEXT` environment variable to be able to run the shortcut from the command prompt without having to type the .LNK extension. If you leave the "Start in" field blank in the shortcut properties, it will inherit the working directory of the parent process (e.g. a cmd shell). However if elevating is required because the parent isn't already elevated, Windows has to create a new console and the working directory is `%SystemRoot%\System32`.